# Summarize across a thousand variables for each observation in Stata

Tags: loops, stata

I have made a loop that creates a variable, `expectedgpa`.

So now I have 1,000 variables for each observation, labeled `expectedgpa1`, `expectedgpa2`...`expectedgpa1000`.

I want to get the average and standard deviation for all the `expectedgpa`s for each observation.

So if I have this

```
Joe       1     2    1    2   4
Sally     2     4    2    4   3
Larry     3     3    3    3   3
```

I want a variable returned that gives

```
Joe 2
Sally 3 
Larry 3
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

**First, for future questions:**

Please post code showing what you've tried. Your question *shows* no research effort.

**Second, to clarify the terminology:**

You created 1000 variables, each
one corresponding to some **expected gpa**. Each observation corresponds 
to a different person. You want, as a result, *three variables*. One with the person's id
and another two with the the mean and sd of the gpa (by person).
This is my interpretation, at least.

One solution involves reshaping your data:

```
clear all
set more off

input ///
str5 id exgpa1 exgpa2 exgpa3 exgpa4 exgpa5
Joe       1     2    1    2   4
Sally     2     4    2    4   3
Larry     3     3    3    3   3
end

list

reshape long exgpa, i(id) j(exgpaid)

collapse (mean) mexgpa=exgpa (sd) sdexgpa=exgpa, by(id)

list
```

Instead of `collapse`, you can also run `by id: summarize exgpa` after the `reshape`, but this doesn't create new variables.

See `help reshape`, `help collapse` and `help summarize` for details.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have created 1000 new variables without a strategy for how you were going to analyse them!

You could also use `egen` functions `rowmean()` and `rowsd()` and keep the same data structure.

A review of working "rowwise" in Stata is accessible at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046